# Datatble Fixed column misaligned in Chrome 78 update

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, datatable

After chrome version update to 78, datatable fixed column designs are broken. no design issues in other browsers or older chrome versions. Issue is shown below [image: Datatable fixed column issue in chrome 78]

Comment: Its working fine [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html). Please include the code

Comment: Its working fine in all browser except chrome 78. 
fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 1
        }

Comment: issue only comes if the column have lengthy text. or html content